# Как отразить массив

Tags: php

Ребят, помогите развернуть массив, из такого:

```
    [add_link] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Name 1
                [1] => Name 2
                [2] => Name 3
            )

        [url] => Array
            (
                [0] => Url 1
                [1] => Url 2
                [2] => Url 3
            )

    )
```

в такой:

```
    [add_link] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array( 'name' => Name 1, 'url' => Url 1 )
        [1] => Array( 'name' => Name 2, 'url' => Url 2 )
        [2] => Array( 'name' => Name 3, 'url' => Url 3 )
    )
```

замучился уже..

массив динамический, приходит из формы, в которую инпуты js`ом добавляются

```
<input name="add_link[name][]" >
<input name="add_link[url][]" >
```

чтобы тупые вопросы мне не задавали - это из оф.документации, способ получения данных из формы с динамическими инпутами, когда их количество не определено
http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.html.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php#example-90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result['add_link'] = array_map(function($name, $url){
                         return ['name' => $name, 'url' => $url];
                  }
                 , $data['add_link']['name']
                 , $data['add_link']['url']);
```

но зачем создавать себе лишние проблемы, и отправлять данные на сервер в неудобном виде? Вместо двух разных массивов `add_link[name][]` наоборот отправляйте их парами `add_link[0][name]` и т.д.

Comment: каким образом, если форма динамическая? и add_link[name][] - это вообще то из оф. документации, как получать значения из нескольких инпутов динамических

Comment: @Alex хорошо, что вы читаете документацию, просто не останавливайте свое чтение на первом похожем месте. я без понятия, каким образом вы строите свою динамическую форму, но влиять это на возможность формирования данных в нужном формате шибко не может. надо лишь приложить чуть-чуть усилий, в итоге на вхоже получите нормальный массив объектов уже сгруппированных

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, работает. Я честно на счет add_link[0] не понял. В html форме там к инпуту ведь не привяжешь несколько name... а делать 2 инпута на одно поле - как то странно, не находите?

Comment: @Alex вот про такое речь - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101453/1216425, принятый ответ в треде - как у вас. два массива. Ответ по ссылке - один массив объектов с полями.

Answer (score 0):

Если кол-во ключей элементов в name и url всегда совпадает, то можно просто перебрать:

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($myArray['add_link']['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $newArray[] = [
        'name' => $name,
        'url' => $myArray['add_link']['url'][$key]
    ];
}

unset ($myArray) // уничтожаем исходный массив если не нужен

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: массив динамический, приходит из формы
<input name="add_link[name][]" >
<input name="add_link[url][]" >